# Unity crashes when changing scenes in the editor but not when built

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a game for the Vive using Steam VR. After updating to 5.5, Unity is freezing when I try to load into roughly half of my scenes when playing in the editor (I have not made any changes), but when I build and run, Unity does not freeze and everything works as would be expected.

I have gone as far as removing all game objects from a scene and replacing the vive camera rig with a unity camera and clearing all baked data, and even then, when I load into the empty scene the Unity editor will still freeze. This is very strange because I can load into some of my other scenes without them being affected.

One thing that I have noted is that the affected scenes that I can not load into I have heavily been working on in 5.5 and not so much in 5.4, so perhaps there is something there?

All of the scenes use the same prefab for a character controller, and the only scripts in my scenes are attached to that. I am really at a loss here. Any ideas or thoughts about things I can try to resolve this would be much appreciated!

As I stated previously, the game builds and runs completely fine, but the editor in play mode freezes when loading into some of my old scenes, even after removing everything from them and only leaving in a Unity camera object to sum it up.

I also have deleted the library folder and reopened my project with Unity and this did not fix it either.